# Division in Java Streams

Tags: java, stream, java-stream, collectors

I have stream of objects. I want to group them and calculate the division of sum of values I get from object functions.

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

record TestRecord(String type, int a, int b) {
    public int getA() { return a; }
    public int getB() { return b; }
}
    
public class Test {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<TestRecord> testRecords = Stream.of(
            new TestRecord("TYPE1", 1, 2),
            new TestRecord("TYPE1", 3, 4),
            new TestRecord("TYPE2", 5, 6),
            new TestRecord("TYPE2", 7, 8),
            new TestRecord("TYPE2", 9, 10)
        );
    }
    
    //It should return {TYPE1= (4/6), TYPE2 = (21 / 24)}
    //TYPE1= (1+3 / 2+4), TYPE2 = ((5+7+9) / (6+8+10))
    public static Map<String, Double> myFunction(Stream<TestRecord> testRecordStream) {
        //TODO
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to return map like {TYPE1= (0.66), TYPE2 = (0.875)}, in above example. I cannot use for loops or forEach function in stream.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve], ideally including any progress you've already made. Concrete examples (with sample data and expected outputs) are *much* easier to work with than somewhat vague descriptions.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for advice. In that case, I have to provide 4 classes and tons of functions. I just want to learn how could it be possible to get sum of 2 functions and divide them in single line.

Comment: No you don't. You just have to provide info on the model of TrainConnection class and with an example.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to first sum the values the function returns and then finally divide or divide the return value of the two functions and sum them. I think it is the former one

Comment: "In that case, I have to provide 4 classes and tons of functions." Is it really impossible to demonstrate what you want without all those classes and functions? We don't need to see your *actual* code - we need to see a minimal representative example which is *just* enough to demonstrate what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I provide a sample class and sample data for my problem. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: FYI, in case you didn't know the record keyword automatically creates both a getter and a field of the same names as the arguments.  In your case, `a`, `a()`, `b`, `b()`, `type`,and `type()` would be created, along with your explicit getters of `getA()` and `getB()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Using Collectors.teeing

If you are using Java 12+ you can use `Collectors.teeing` to solve this.

We pass two *Collectors* to `Collectors.teeing`; the first one sums the return values of function `a()` and the second for function `b()`. In the `merger` function of teeing, we divide the summed values.

```
public static Map<String, Double> myFunction(Stream<TestRecord> testRecordStream) {
    return testRecordStream
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TestRecord::type,
                    Collectors.teeing(
                            Collectors.summingDouble(TestRecord::a),
                            Collectors.summingDouble(TestRecord::b),
                            (a, b) -> a / b)
            ));
}
```

### 2 Using Collectors.reducing + Collectors.collectingAndThen

In case, you are using Java version < 12, then you can use *reduction* mechanism to reduce (here it is sum) the values for a given type. But this would require a simple auxiliary class.

```
private class Pair {
    private final int l;
    private final int r;
    //Constructors, getters skipped
}
```

The *reducing* Collector is used from within a *collectingAndThen* Collector.

- The first argument of the reducing collector is the *identity value* (`new Pair(0, 0)`).
- The second argument maps an instance of `TestRecord` to a `Pair`.
- The final argument merges two Pair instances by summing the left and right value (which is `l` and `r` here).

Finally, after reducing, we would have a single `Pair` instance whose `l` is equal to the sum of all `a()` function values and `r` is the sum of all `b()` function values (for a given `type`). We divide these two in the *finisher* of the `collectingAndThen` Collector.

```
public static Map<String, Double> myFunction(Stream<TestRecord> testRecordStream) {
    return testRecordStream
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TestRecord::type,
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.reducing(new Pair(0, 0),
                                    testRecord -> new Pair(testRecord.a(), testRecord.b()),
                                    (p1, p2) -> new Pair(p1.l + p2.l, p1.r + p2.r)),
                            pair -> (double) pair.l / pair.r
                    )));
}
```